# how to import data from Excel sheet to SQL Server using SSIS by counting through the number of sheets

Tags: ssis

I am doing an application where in I have to import data form excel workbook having multiple sheets and the count of the shets is not known exactly and I need to get the data from these multiple sheets to the SQL Server.I need to do this using SSIS.

Please help me out.....

Thanks in Advance...